# Are the partial derivatives of any order n and below of a continuously differentiable function of order n with a compact supported set bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, compactness, upper-lower-bounds

Let $C_c^n\left(\Omega\right)$ be the set of all the continuously differentiable function of order n with a compact supported set included in $\Omega$. I've already known that $\forall f\in C_c^n\left(\Omega\right)$, $f$ is bounded. But, is any partial derivative of order $m$ that less than or equal to $n$ of $f$ also bounded? That is $\left|D^\alpha f\right|\le M,\left|\alpha\right|=m\le n$, where $\alpha$ is a multi-index.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).  To begin with, how do you "know" (i.e. prove) that $∀f∈C^n_c(Ω)$, $f$ is bounded (even if $n=0$)? Next (hint): if $f∈C^n_c(Ω)$, notice that $D^αf∈C^0_c(Ω), ∀|α|\le n.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ has compact support, the derivatives $D^\alpha f$ have compact support for $|\alpha|\leq n$. Since the derivatives are continuous on this compact set, $D^\alpha f$ are bounded for all $|\alpha|\leq n$.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should [encourage the person who posted the question to improve it](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4755483/timeline#comment_10237948).